# NumberFormatException Java

Tags: java, исключения

Нужно сделать класс, который спрашивает у пользователя целое число, умножает его на 2 и выводит это. Преобразовать полученный от пользователя данные в число использую Integer.parseInt метод. Пользователь может еще и текст вводить ( не только Integer ) - в этом случаи метод parseInt должен выкинуть ( NumberFormat Exception ) ошибку. Добавить catch-блок, что поймает эту ошибку и спросить у пользователя новое число.

Я понимаю, что в try надо запихнуть while цикл, что бы постоянно спрашивал, пока input равен числу. Что то я совсем туплю.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Korrutaja {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Type: ");
        String sümbol = sc.nextLine();;
        Scanner ss = null;
        while (){
            try {
                ss = new Scanner(System.in);
                System.out.println("Type: ");

            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("NumberFormatException");
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```java
public class Korrutaja {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        int num;
        while (true) {  // Запускаем бесконечный цикл
            System.out.println("Type: ");
            String str = sc.nextLine();
            try {
                num = Integer.parseInt(str);  // Пытаемся преобразовать в число
                break;  // если получилось - выходим из цикла
            } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
                System.out.println("NumberFormatException");
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Number: " + num);
    }
}
```